# C# Refresh DataGridView with another Form

Tags: c#, forms, datagridview

I have a problem with not being able to refresh my form that has a `DataGridView`.
I open a form called MaintenanceForm.
Here I will choose a car, give the amount of km, and the option to add products. 
If I click on the add products button, this form will stay open while another will open as well called AddProducts. In this form I will choose from a list of products that I will add to my final listbox. If I click Save, these items will go to my BindingList and populate my grid.
I have tested this with closing my first form first and reopening it with my second form. The grid was populated.
How do I populate my grid without having to close my first form?
Here are the methods I'm using

Save button on my second form:

```
private void btnOpslaan_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lstTotal = new BindingList<Product>();
    foreach (object product in listBtotal.Items)
    {
        lstTotal.Add((Product)product);

    }
    MaintenanceForm maintenanceForm = new MaintenanceForm();
    maintenanceForm.FillDataGridView(lstTotal);
    this.Close();
}
```

Method to populate my grid:

```
public void FillDataGridView(BindingList<Product> products)
{
    dGvProducts.DataSource = null;
    dGvProducts.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    dGvProducts.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
    dGvProducts.DataSource = products;
    dGvProducts.Refresh();

}
```

Again the MaintenanceForm is still open while AddProductsForm is open?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why u creating a new instance of `MaintenanceForm ` inside your save button? Isn't the save button is part of the `AddProducts` form, which is the child of `MaintenanceForm ` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the user JDB i have fixed my problem.

Instead of making a new instance (Thank you Junaith for correcting me for it) I'm now making a LogicalParent method.

public AdminForm LogicalParent { get; set; }

With this i have access to al methods and functions of my parent Form and no problems with refreshing.